# ERROR: tensorflow: Image directory ' ' not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd

I am trying use Tensorflow for Poets 2 with Windows 10 and Anaconda Prompt. However, I'm having troubles with training my images when I run this code:

```
python scripts/retrain.py
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks         
--how_many_training_steps 500
--model_dir=/{$your-working_directory}/inception
--output_graph=/{$your-working_directory}/retrained_graph.pb
--output_labels=/{$your-working_directory}/retrained_labels.txt
--image_dir /tf_files/paintings
```

I have two folders where both of them contain images in .jpg format. These two folders are inside "paintings" folder.

Even though I specify the image directory I still get this error:

```
2018-09-04 19:40:46.876487: W 
T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\op_def_util.cc:346] Op 
BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to work in 
GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().

ERROR:tensorflow:Image directory '' not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\JOHN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _ 
run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\JOHN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in 
_run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\JOHN\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrain.py", line 1326, 
in <module>
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
File "C:\Users\JOHN\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "C:\Users\JOHN\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrain.py", line 989, in 
main
class_count = len(image_lists.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I have checked similar posts about this problem but they were not useful in my case.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please show the complete path of your `tf_files` folder?

Comment: It is: C:\Users\JOHN\tensorflow-for-poets-2\tf_files. Inside tf_files I have the folder "paintings". And inside "paintings", I have "vangogh" and "picasso" folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/tf_files` means that the `tf_files` folder is under your main directory (that's the meaning of `/`), which is not the case.

You should remove all the leading slashes `/` from your directory arguments, i.e.

```
python scripts/retrain.py
--bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks         
--how_many_training_steps=500
--model_dir={$your-working_directory}/inception
--output_graph={$your-working_directory}/retrained_graph.pb
--output_labels={$your-working_directory}/retrained_labels.txt
--image_dir=tf_files/paintings
```

assuming of course that the shell variable `your-working_directory` has already been defined (if not, replace it with your actual working directory).

Comment: I shaped the code as: python scripts/retrain.py  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks  --how_many_training_steps=500 --model_dir=tf_files/models  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" --image_dir=tf_files/paintings. Now I get this error: ERROR:tensorflow:Couldn't understand architecture name '${architecture}'

Comment: @kripto_birader please, try leaving out the `--summaries_dir` & `--architecture` arguments, as in your initial code, and try again (changing the code while seeking the errors cause is not a good idea); in the [repo](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#3) the `ARCHITECTURE` shell variable is defined first...