# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tf_files/retrained_graph.pb'

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd

I am trying use Tensorflow for Poets 2 with Windows 10 and Anaconda Prompt. After I retrained my images I wanted to test them by writing this code:

```
python scripts/label_image.py  --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  --image=tf_files/test_pic.jpg
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scripts/label_image.py", line 112, in <module>
graph = load_graph(model_file)
File "scripts/label_image.py", line 31, in load_graph
with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'tf_files/retrained_graph.pb'
```

By the way, these were the last three messages after my retraining was finished:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Final test accuracy = 96.2% (N=52)
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 2 variables.
INFO:tensorflow:Converted 2 variables to const ops.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you use the argument `--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb` when retraining, as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170932/error-tensorflow-image-directory-not-found)?

Comment: I realized that I didn't. Fixed it and it started to test my images. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly include the argument `--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb` when retraining; following up from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170932/error-tensorflow-image-directory-not-found):

```
python scripts/retrain.py 
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks 
  --how_many_training_steps=500 
  --model_dir=tf_files/models 
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb    
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txx
  --image_dir=tf_files/paintings
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your script can not find your `tf_files` folder.

You should use absolute to be sure your script can access your files or simply move your folder in the `scripts` dir.